# Problem with url_for and named routes in ActionMailer View: "Need controller and action"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment, routes, actionmailer

I'm attempting to provide a confirmation link in my user welcome email and I'm getting the following Rails error:

```
Need controller and action!
```

It makes a fuss about this line:

```
<p>Please take a moment to activate your account by going to: 
<%= link_to confirm_user_url(:id => @user.confirmation_code) %>.</p>
```

In my `development.rb` environment, I have the following line:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
  :host => "localhost", :port => 3000
}
```

---

There's no problem with the `@user` variable. I've tested the email with things like `@user.username` and `@user.confirmation_code`. I'm only getting trouble with `url_for` and named routes like `confirm_user_url`.

When I check my routes with `rake routes`, `confirm_user` shows up, so it's not an issue with the named route not existing.

I can't seem to figure it out. What gives?

Comment: How did you define your confirm_user route?

Comment: @Corey, as I noted, the confirm_user route has no problem associated with it. If you're simply curious, I'm using `map.resources :users, :collection => {:signup => :get, :register => :post}, :member => {:confirm => :get}`

Comment: I see from your comment on the answer that you worked out that link_to you needed two parameters.  I was about to suggest auto_link(confirm_user_url(:id => @user.confirmation_code) when I read that comment.

Comment: @Corey, very cool. I did not know about `auto_link`. If it's worth anything to you, post it as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted as it's more elegant than `link_to( foo, foo )` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since having a clickable url is what you said in your where after in your comment, here you go macek

```
<p>Please take a moment to activate your account by going to: 
<%= auto_link confirm_user_url(:id => @user.confirmation_code) %>.</p>
```

I've used the [`auto_link`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#M001752) helper in some of my mailers to make urls clickable and it has worked out pretty well.  I think that does email addresses also, check out the full api for all the options.  Enjoy.

Comment: `auto_link` was removed from Rails in 3.1: https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink

Answer (score 10):

ActionMailer isn't a real Rails controller, so routes aren't available in your mailer templates. You need to set up instance variables in your mailer class to pass values to the template.

eg. if your mailer is SampleMailer:

```
class SampleMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def confirmation_mail(user)
    subject    'Confirmation'
    recipients user.email
    from       'sample@example.com'
    sent_on    Time.now
    body       :greeting => 'Sample Greeting', :email => user.email,
               :confirm_user_url => confirm_user_url(:id=>@user.confirmation_code)
  end
end
```

Then in the template:

```
<%= link_to "Confirmation link", @confirm_user_url %>
```

This is explained somewhat cryptically in the [api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) in the "ActionMailer" section, and in more detail in [Agile Web Development with Rails, 3rd Ed.](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails-third-edition), Chapter 25.

Comment: @zetetic, this was less of a strange problem than I thought. The issue wasnt' that I was using `confirm_user_url()` in the ActionMailer View, it was because I was only specifying one argument to `link_to`. I needed to specify `link_to confirm_user_url(:id => @user.confirmation_code), confirm_user_url(:id => @user.confirmation_code)`. Because that's hideous, I used part of your method so I can just use `link_to @confirm_link, @confirm_link`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I thought my answer was well-written, well-researched and concise. I see now that it also missed the point :)

Comment: yeah, it still helped me get to where I wanted to be so I gave you a +1.